# Posts are suddenly being deleted in Wordpress?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

Hello I have migrated my Wordpress to a new host using Duplicator, but when I add new posts, they are deleted after some time. My website resets to the old settings.

Comment: Do u have data backup ?

Comment: I have a server backup

Answer (score 0):

Just Disable the "Duplicator" plugin. Also, if you installed any new plugin try disabling that as well.